# Adding titles and formatting Y-axis labels for multiple plots produced by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a multiplot with 10 scatter plots produced using ggplot2. The code i have used to create the plot has been lifted from here [R cookbook.](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/) My problem is that i want to add different titles for each and every scatter plot e.g., plot 1 title can be titled "plot 1", while plot 2 can be titled "plot 2" and so on and so forth. I would also want to change the labels from the current label "Y" to "purchases" for all the plots.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Use `sprintf` or `paste` to make your label in a call to `labs` in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your plots and title each one individually as the code you referenced does. Then arrange using the `gridExtra` package. `ggtitle` does the title, the `ylab` function can be used for the y-label.

```
library(ggplot2)

# This example uses the ChickWeight dataset, which comes with ggplot2
# First plot
p1 <- ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Diet, group=Chick)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle("Growth curve for individual chicks")

# Second plot
p2 <- ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, colour=Diet)) +
    geom_point(alpha=.3) +
    geom_smooth(alpha=.2, size=1) +
    ggtitle("Fitted growth curve per diet")

 # Third plot
p3 <- ggplot(subset(ChickWeight, Time==21), aes(x=weight, colour=Diet)) +
    geom_density() +
    ggtitle("Final weight, by diet")

# Fourth plot
p4 <- ggplot(subset(ChickWeight, Time==21), aes(x=weight, fill=Diet)) +
    geom_histogram(colour="black", binwidth=50) +
    facet_grid(Diet ~ .) +
    ggtitle("Final weight, by diet") +
    theme(legend.position="none")        # No legend (redundant in this graph)    

require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow = 2)
```

Comment: much appreciated